# Using windows workflows in ASP.NET MVC / WEb Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

So I'm new to workflows and I'm trying to include a workflow that handles user registation in my Web API project. Currently I just initialize it in the controller as follows:

```
 public class AccountController : ApiController
 {
       private readonly RegistrationVerification<AccountRegistration> verification = 
           new RegistrationVerification<AccountRegistration>();
 }
```

Now this works, but aside from looking like a code smell, it also causes errors in my Web Api Project:

```
The type or namespace name `AccountRegistration` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

With `AccountRegistration` refering to the .xaml defined workflow in a seperate (referenced) project.

These error show up in my Error List and AccountRegistration has red squiglies but they ultimately do not prevent me from compiling and running the application. They are a big nuisance and eye-sore however.

I tried adding references in my Web Api to some of workflow assemblies like System.Activities, System.Activities.DurableInstancing, System.Drawing... but none clear this up.

So the question is how do I properly utilize a windows workflow in a Web API? Typically I would inject such a dependency but I'm not sure how to even do that and whether or not it would make those annoying error go away.

Comment: Can you share the errors that are listed in the Error List?

Comment: Why not expose your Windows Workflow as a Web Service? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163623.aspx#S5

Comment: @DrewMarsh  The error is: The type or namespace name 'AccountRegistration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). The workflow project is referenced and liek I said this does not make compilation fail.

Comment: Do you by chance reference any Portable Class Library (PCL) assemblies in your workflow project?

Comment: I don't believe so. I haven't made use of them myself either.